# Update missed calls notification on android

Tags: android

I need to cancel the missed calls notification for a certain number. I've seen the NotificationMgr class on com.android.phone but i'm unable to call it trough reflection. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will cancel the missed call notification.

To get the method work correctly, you must gain MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission in AndroidManifest.xml like

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
String Log_Tag = "log";
try
    {
        Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        Method getServiceMethod = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
        Object phoneService = getServiceMethod.invoke(null, "phone");
        Class ITelephonyClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony");
        Class ITelephonyStubClass = null;
        for(Class clazz : ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredClasses())
        {
            if (clazz.getSimpleName().equals("Stub"))
            {
                ITelephonyStubClass = clazz;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ITelephonyStubClass != null)
        {
            Class IBinderClass = Class.forName("android.os.IBinder");
            Method asInterfaceMethod = ITelephonyStubClass.getDeclaredMethod("asInterface",
                    IBinderClass);
            Object iTelephony = asInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, phoneService);
            if (iTelephony != null)
            {
                Method cancelMissedCallsNotificationMethod = iTelephony.getClass().getMethod(
                        "cancelMissedCallsNotification");
                cancelMissedCallsNotificationMethod.invoke(iTelephony);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Telephony service is null, can't call "
                        + "cancelMissedCallsNotification");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unable to locate ITelephony.Stub class!");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                "Failed to clear missed calls notification due to ClassNotFoundException!", ex);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                "Failed to clear missed calls notification due to InvocationTargetException!",
                ex);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                "Failed to clear missed calls notification due to NoSuchMethodException!", ex);
    } catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to clear missed calls notification due to Throwable!", ex);
    }
```

The original link is
http://sites.google.com/site/t2k269group/development-diary/reset-missed-calls-notification

If some know how to use the reflection to access class in com.android.phone, please tell me.

Comment: Anyone using this is asking for trouble, as it may not work on all versions of Android (past/present/future) and it may not work on all Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot affect anyone other application's `Notifications`, let alone one for missed calls.

Comment: While I agree with CommonsWare that you can't/shouldn't cancel other applications notifications, the above code works to cancel the stock Missed Calls Notification. Thanks :)