# How i read missed calls and remove missed calls notification in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing a `dialer app`. If I open the call log, missed calls not be checked like in the original `Dialer` or `ExDialer`. Missed calls will be checked and notification remove after I open Dialer. Code in this  posts

[how to mask missed calls to read in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561167/how-to-mask-missed-calls-to-read-in-android)

> and

[Update missed calls notification on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720967/update-missed-calls-notification-on-android) 
 doesn't work.

I have two devices: HTC ONE S Android 4.2.2 with Sesnse 5.0 and Nexus 5 Android 4.4 without shell and code above doesn't work on both devices.

So, how can I mark missed calls as read in database and remove notification?